# Generic JMS client library for Weblogic, Webshere and JBoss servers

Tags: jms

We have a requirement for one standalone **Java** application that can **push** JMS message to a JMS queue configured on **Weblogic**, **Websphere** and **JBoss** application server.

Is there any **generic JMS client** library available, that we can use in our application for pushing the messages to any or all of these servers?

As we understand, there is a specific JMS client for each server (for e.g. *wljmsclient.jar* required for *Weblogic* target server, as we would need *weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory* to be available as Initial Context factory class, *similarly* for Websphere and JBoss). And we would like to avoid having 3 different JMS client libraries (1 each for server) in the same application.

However, the catch here is, destination server is not known during compilation time. Only during **runtime**, it will be known whether the given message is to be pushed to Weblogic, Websphere or JBoss server or all of them. Hence, there is a need for a deployed application to support all 3 servers during runtime.

Is there any alternative generic JMS client library?

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your own client that supports the 3 servers.

Basically you need to have for your standalone application :

- The different JMS provider jar on the classpath
- For example a `jms_config.properties` file which stores the configuration for each server (initial context factory, etc.)

Then from a generic code you can build the `InitialContext`, JMS Queues, etc.  depending on the target server.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I can add configuration like you mentioned, however my query was to see if there is a way to avoid having App server specific libraries in classpath, and if I can just have one **generic library** supporting all App Servers (if such thing exists?)

Comment: I do not think you can have a generic library support all servers (how can this generic library known about servers version, etc. ?) What is your problem with having App servers library on the classpath?